# Prevent previous window from opening in Sublime

Tags: sublimetext3

Anyone know how to prevent Sublime from opening the previous window / session when using the command line?  This happens in both OSX and Windows.  If I open a folder by passing the path to the app, a session with the folder opens, but so does the previous window / session / folder...

[image: Example screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to preferences -> Settings - User
Add:

```
{
  "hot_exit": false,
  "remember_open_files": false
}
```